# Is there a way to develop dynamic sql query in spring boot app with jdbc?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, rest, spring-data-jdbc

I am developing backend for a webapp in Spring Boot using Spring Data JDBC with MYSQL(phpmyadmin) database.
The problem is, there is a table ClientInfo with more than 12 columns. Client may query the backend by any number of parameters(columns in database). Should I write controller and sql query for every condition provided by client or is there better way to appraoch to solve this problem.

**Edited:** Actually I am not using ORM. I am using JDBC and JDBI.

Comment: Check if this helps https://javadeveloperzone.com/spring/spring-jpa-dynamic-query-example/#:~:text=Steps%20to%20Generate%20Dynamic%20Query%20In%20Spring%20JPA%3A,-Extends%20JpaSpecificationExecutor%20in&text=Write%20Specification%20for%20the%20query,will%20generate%20a%20dynamic%20query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring Data JPA Query by Example. Depending on what the client provides, you build an *org.springframework.data.domain.Example* and then you use it in the query:

```
ClientInfo c = new ClientInfo();
c.setFirstName("Bill");
Example<ClientInfo> example = Example.of(c);    
List<ClientInfo> results = clientInfoRepository.findAll(example);
```

In this case the ClientInfoRepository needs to extend JpaRepository:

```
public interface ClientInfoRepository extends JpaRepository<ClientInfo, Long> {}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sql query part:  12 columns are not a lot.  You probably can use handy OR-mapping (JPA/hibernate) to retrieve the result into a ClientInfo object at the backend.

For the controller part:  from my understanding you're returning selected-fields in resulted data sending back to a web client based on certain request parameters.  Suppose you're returning a json result using a spring web controller, you probably can also only create a single controller.  And then control what to be included in the replied json.  Applying simple technique/logic should be able to achieve this - for example if you use jackson for json handling you may set all the fields you don't want to include as null, and then use @JsonInclude NON_NULL annotations to exclude them.

Comment: Actually I am using JDBC and JDBI not ORM.

Comment: I see. Using jdbc you’ll need to construct your sql dynamically instead.   it is also fine but just pay attention to avoid sql injection - using binding sql variables and in your case when doing concatenation of the select clause control to use predefined set of column names instead of freely using the parameters from the client request.